# Enclosing the string with double quotes

Tags: php, string

I am trying to handle text which may contains single quotes and other special char. If it is enclised with single quote, it does not proceed. So I am trying to enclose single quoted string into double quoted string.

I already checked previous threads.

Here is the code:

Check result : http://ideone.com/gWFdUb

```
<?php
function clean($string) {
    eval('$string = "'.$string.'";');
   $string = str_replace(' ', ' ', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 @\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}

$d =  clean('this was readlly n'ice 'test for@me to') ;
echo $d;
```

What wrong with eval line?

I am processing user tweets, post for two purpose.

1. To store into mysql table. (mysqli_real_escape) did not help
2. To process the each string into text for matching and POS(part of speech) tagging.

I get stuck due to such characters in text. So trying to remove it before I start processing.

**UPDATE:**

Check this, here I am already using `mysqli_real_escape_String` even the script stops when it reach this

```
...
mention-179
May Thanks @ShaleMarkets @01Finser @52York @AB_CutRock @AFSPG @AJSmith222 @AlbertaEnergy @andymartin @annemullettamg @APGQ_officiel-440929408564477952-Tue Mar 04 19:18:57 +0000 2014-19:03:572014:03:04201403Adnan Aftab Nizamani0131

mention-180
Thank you for @ShaleMarkets, to promoting, thank you very much for an award. Glad to have been able to help you :)-440897048963850240-Tue Mar 04 17:10:22 +0000 2014-17:03:222014:03:04201403♘-₭ℜi℘-0582

mention-181
@ShaleMarkets https://t.co/aM8liykQqR-440890009273393152-Tue Mar 04 16:42:24 +0000 2014-16:03:242014:03:04201403Bre Burey018
```

What's wrong in mention-181 so that it got stuck? Here is the code

```
    foreach ($tweets1 as $item)
    {       
        $count = $count + 1;
        $text = $item->text;
        //echo $userid.$text;
        $text_id = $item->id;
        $constant = 'mention';
        $time = $item->created_at;
        //echo $time;
        //$dt = new DateTime('@' . strtotime($time));
        $dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s e Y', $time);
        //var_dump($dt);
        $tweet_time = $dt->format('H:m:s');
        $tweet_dtm = $dt->format('Y:m:d');
        $year =  $dt->format('Y'); 
        $month =  $dt->format('m'); 
        $user_name = $item->user->name;
//      echo $year.$month.$user_name;
        $inreplyto =  $item->in_reply_to_screen_name;
        $rt_count = $item->retweet_count;
        $follower_count = $item->user->followers_count;
        echo $constant."-".$count."<br>".$text."-".$text_id."-".$time."-".$tweet_time.$tweet_dtm.$year.$month.$user_name.$rt_count.$follower_count."<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root', 'root');         
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            return;
        }
        $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$text);
        $insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO twitter_mention(`username`,`userid`,`tweet_text`,`text_id`,`time`,`month`,`year`,`date`,`user_follower_count`,`rt_count`,`constant`,`in_reply_to`) VALUES ('".$twitteruser."','".$userid."','".$text."','".$text_id."','".$tweet_time."','".$month."','".$year."','".$tweet_dtm."','".$follower_count."','".$rt_count."','".$constant."','".$inreplyto."')";

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$insertQuery1))
        {
        //  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        //  echo "error";
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using eval?

Comment: note that `str_replace(' ', ' ', $string);` looks strange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Always use contextual escaping

You can't generically "clean" data without any context of what it's for. Do not try to build a single function to handle all the possible cases. Just don't. It's pointless. In your function, you're trying to "*clean*" the string by removing certain characters. **You can't clean a string by removing a set of characters.**  That idea is flawed because you're always going to have to allow the use of some characters that are special in some syntax or the other.

Instead, treat the string according to the context where it's going to be used. For example:

- If you are going to use this string in an SQL query, you have to use prepared statements (or [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)) to properly escape the data.
- If you're going to output this value in HTML markup, you need to use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to escape the data.
- If you're going to use it as  command-line argument, you need to use [`escapeshellcmd()`](http://php.net/escapeshellcmd) or [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg).

Further reading:

- [Security.SE — What's the best way to sanitize user input in PHP?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42498/best-way-to-sanitize-user-input-in-php)
- [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)
- [Does eliminating dangerous characters avoid SQL-injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873074/does-removing-dangerous-characters-avoid-sql-injection)

Comment: I am already using `mysql_real_escape` even it get stopped in for each during data insertion

Comment: I am here using mysql_real_escape to store the data into table, even it does not proceed while inserting data into table

Answer (score 4):

In this answer, I'll try to address your original question:

> What wrong with eval line?

Nothing. The second-to-last line is the only line that contains a syntax error. You aren't escaping the single-quotes correctly. Try the following:

```
$d = clean('this was readlly n\'ice \'test for@me to');
```

It should now produce this output:

```
this was readlly nice test for@me to
```

I'm not sure if this is the expected result. If you update the question to include what exactly you're trying to achieve and **why do you care which type of quotes the string was wrapped in**, maybe I can help you find a solution.

Comment: Thanks @Amal: but user who enters the string they dont put `\`. consider it as user tweet

Comment: @user123: I have no idea what you're trying to say. You have a tweet. And now what? What do you want to do with it? How do you want the tweet to be modified? **What's the final result you're trying to achieve?**

Comment: @user123: OK, that's better. But I'm still not quite sure what's the final output that you're expecting. Are you trying to just remove all type of quotes (and other special characters) from the string?

Comment: Yes, I want to get simple string which does not stopped by mysql or other string processing functions

Comment: That's pointless. **You should only ever escape based on *context***. There's no bullet-proof way to `clean` a string so it would work everywhere. If you're inserting the string in an SQL query, you need to use `mysqli_real_escape()` or prepared statements. If you're going to output it in a webpage, you need to use `htmlspecialchars()` to guard against XSS attacks.

Comment: During stroring into table if I use `mysqli_real_escape` and while fetching from tb to display on web page if I use `htmlspecialchars()`, then will it handle any text?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one-

```
<?php
function clean($string) {
    eval("\$string = \"$string\";");
   $string = str_replace(' ', ' ', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
   return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}

$d =  clean("this was readlly n'ice 'test for@me to") ;
echo $d;
?>
```

The output is- `this was readlly nice test forme to`

Comment: ok..then try it- return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 @\-]/', '', $string);   It will not remove @ from string.

Comment: thanks, what you say will it work for all kinda text?

Comment: @shashank: What would this function accomplish? It's pointless, TBH.

Comment: Also, you probably meant `$string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string);` instead. Currently it does nothing.