# Insert values containing special characters into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently trying to setup a comment system with TinyMCE, it's all working with normal characters and PHP tags and so on. But when I comment with this `ed o'neill`, it just inserts an empty row in my db.

I have `htmlspecialchars` and `mysqli_real_escape_string` on the input from my form.

How can I fix the empty row insert?

```
$post_content = $_POST['post_content'];
                        //$post_content = htmlspecialchars($post_content);
                        //$post_content = mysqli_real_escape_string($post_content);
```

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: Its 2014, Really better use a modern library for working with Mysql or look @ PDO

Comment: There was code, for like 10 seconds, then it was gone.

Comment: [**Always use contextual escaping.**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23076661/1438393). `htmlspecialchars` has nothing to do here — it's for preventing XSS attacks. You only need to escape the special characters alone. For that, either use `m_r_e_s()` **alone** or use prepared statements (preferred option).

Comment: Im stil "new" to php, what do you mean with prepared statement? like OOP ? or

Comment: Anyway, it dosent work with m_r_e_s($post_content)

Comment: you have commented some of your code and mysqli_real_escape_string requires 2 parameters `string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )`

Comment: [**Right here => read up on prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I forgot the database connection in the escape string.. :) Will def read on prepared statements.  Thank you so much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2864740

Comment: FYI: Using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` alone won't guarantee that an apostrophe won't show up as `\'` in DB. Include `stripslashes()` as well.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It will guarantee that "ed o'neill" is saved as `ed o'neill`. Slashes are irrelevant to any SQL portion of the problem.

Comment: @user2864740 Sorry but I beg to differ. I say this from experience.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Then defend the position: ***How*** are slashes relevant to the SQL *data*? (The *data* is not necessarily a valid SQL *string literal*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have commented some of your code but `mysqli_real_escape_string` requires 2 parameters see for more information [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

```
string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr );
```

Your code should be :

```
$post_content = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$post_content); //$connection should be your database connection string
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at prepared statements, it will do all the escaping for you

EDIT: [Here's the link to the PHP manual, courtesy of Fred -ii-](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: You mean [**like this?**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: That's what i mean yeah

Comment: *Ahh*, I thought so ;-)